# jquery autocomplete ui changes order of elements in response

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
$array = array('All' => array( 5=>array(a=>'1',b=>'3'),9=>array(a=>'5',b=>'6'),4=>array(a=>'6',b=>'3')
```

)

I am sending a json_encode($array) as the response from the php, 
and when I console.log the data received I get:

```
$array = array('All' => array( 4=>array(a=>'6',b=>'3'), 5=>array(a=>'1',b=>'3'),9=>array(a=>'5',b=>'6')
```

)
the array keys are reordered ASC, why? and how to cancel?

I am using the jquery autocomplete ui.

Comment: Looks like your "array" is probably an "object" in JSON and JavaScript terminology, and JavaScript objects don't have any inherent ordering of their properties (so when iterated the browser is free to order them as it sees fit). Is that really your `console.log()` output? (In PHP format?)

Comment: yes it is really my consol.log output, please remember I am using the autocomplete ui, so this most be something to do with it. on a regular ajax send and receive the order of the elements doesn't change.

Comment: Why would the `console.log()` output the `$array =` part? That's not part of the response sent to the browser. Why would the browser use PHP format at all? I'm not aware of any browsers that would do that - which browser are you testing with?

Comment: no man, its just for the example. console.log doesn't output in php format.

Comment: So the real output is using object syntax curly brackets `{}`, right? Which means my original comment about it being an object which doesn't have an inherent ordering of properties is true.

Comment: You are correct, the ajax/json messes up the ordering.